# Datepicker not working after jQuery.load execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've got a problem trying to display datepickers in a new JSP, after called it with Jquery.load function. No datapcikers are showing up unless I use this command:

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div").remove();
```

But if I do, the others datepickers that I have in the main jsp stop working.

The new JSP is called from the main like this:

```
$('#divNewJSP').load("myServlet?OP=1, function() {
    $('#divNewJSP').slideDown();
```

The servlet executes correctly and I have the following code running in the new JSP, at the beggining fo the document:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('#dateField').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["pt"]);
$('#dateField').datepicker("show")
...
```

I've been trying several options but no one seems to work...Any ideas please?

Thx in advance.

**EDIT**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/monitor.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.js?ver=a0.8185263484592263"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
createDatatable();
// Datepickers
/*$("#ui-datepicker-div").remove();*/ <------ IT WORKS WITH THIS
//*** ORIGINAL DATEPICKERS INIT ***//
/*  $('#dateField1').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $('#dateField2').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $('#dateField3').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $('#dateField4').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["es"]);*/
});

    <body>
<div id="blockResult">
        <div id="formCriteraRC"><br/>
           <fieldset style="float:left;border:1px solid #007E3A;padding:0.5em;margin-bottom:0.5em;width:98%;">
              <legend class="caption">Search Criteria</legend>
              <table>
                 <tr>                                                        
                 <tr>
                    <div class="intrnot_small">
                        <span class="labelDateField">Date 1:</span>
                        <input type="text" class="bloquesinmargen campo" id="dateField1" value="" />
                        <span class="labelDateField">Date 2:</span>
                        <input type="text" class="bloquesinmargen campo" id="dateField2" value="" />
                    </div>                          
                 </tr>
                 <tr>   
                    <div class="intrnot_small>
                        <span class="labelDateField">Date 3:</span>
                        <input type="text" class="bloquesinmargen campo" id="dateField3" value="" />        
                        <span class="labelDateField">Date 4:</span>
                        <input type="text" class="bloquesinmargen campo" id="dateField4" value="" />
                    </div>
                </tr><br/>
                <tr>
                <div class="intrnot_small"> 
                    <input type="button" id="search value="Search" disabled>
                    <input type="button" id="clean" value="Clean">
                </div> 
                </tr>                       
              </table>
           </fieldset>
        </div> <!-- end form -->
    <div id="listData">     
        <table id="datatableReg" class="display nowrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;">       
        <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th width="15px">Sel.</th>
                    <th width="120px">Id</th>
                    <th width="90px">Origin</th>
                    <th width="80px">C&oacute;de</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
    </table>                        
</div>  <!-- end -->
</div> 
<div id="divDetailResult" class="bloquesinmargen" style='overflow-x: hidden; height: 99%; width: 99%; max-width:99%; display: none; top:0px;'>  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2: MAIN JSP CALLING (from its .js)

```
function openNewJSP(){
    $('#divNewJSP').load("myServlet?OP=1", function() {
    $('#divNewJSP').slideDown();
    $('#dateField1').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["pt"]);
    $('#dateField2').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["pt"]);
    $('#dateField3').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["pt"]);
    $('#dateField4').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["pt"]);
});
}
```

Comment: I see that a quote is missing in .load("myServlet?OP=1",

Comment: Yes, my fault coying. The servlet runs Ok.

Comment: This `jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js` is declared in your parent JSP?

Comment: Yes it is. There's another jsp loaded in a div that uses it

Answer (score 0):

**You have to execute the `datepicker` function inside of your callback:**

```
$('#divNewJSP').load("myServlet?OP=1", function() {
   $('#divNewJSP').slideDown();
   $('#dateField').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["pt"]);
   $('#dateField').datepicker("show");
});
```

**Remove the following code from your JSP (servlet response):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#dateField').datepicker($.datepicker.regional["pt"]);
   $('#dateField').datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: Hi, and thx for the answer. I already tried that but still not working at all. I'm running out of ideas. '#dateField' does not exist in the the main JSP (it exist in the new one).

Comment: Can you share the response from your servlet?